# scraping not working - InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape the yahoo finance webpage (comment section). I want to click on a button whose class is seen in the picture below:
[image]

I want to select the button with the following code, but I am getting an `InvalidSelectorException`. I do not understand why.

Note that in my code I have replaced the space with `.` because that's what I usually do, but I have also tried without replace the spaces and in both cases it is not working.

```
link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/community?p=AMD'
path = r"""chromedriver.exe"""
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
driver.get(link)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('sort-filter-button.O(n):h.O(n):a.Fw(b).M(0).P(0).Ff(i).C(#000).Fz(16px)')
```

Comment: @prophet hi, if you don't mind answering this one too :p

Comment: @YaDavMaNish anyone can answer, it is just that I know this person answers, so in case there is no one else I thought it was a good idea to mention this person

Comment: can you check my answer hope it will work for you

Comment: It's a selenium bug. Just don't use by_class_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the below

```
#This page is taking more time to load

sleep(15)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Sort Reactions']")

element.click()
```

**update**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'sort-filter-button')]")

element.click()
```

Comment: it worked thanks! can you explain a little bit how it works and why my solution did not work? Don't worry, I will accept your answer once, it is all settled

Comment: Well I don't worry about the `repu` it is just learning, I think it because this class name  `sort-filter-button O(n):h O(n):a Fw(b) M(0) P(0) Ff(i) C(#000) Fz(16px)`is having  the `():#` you can check it here  https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#find-element